# Vertical aligning the first-level slides in Quarto revealjs

Tags: css, markdown, quarto, reveal.js

I am creating a presentation in Reveal using Quarto markdown with horizontal and vertical slides. The content of the first-level slides is vertically centered, is there a way (possibly using CSS) to have it aligned at the top of the slide?

```
---
title: "My presentation"
format: revealjs
---

# First horizontal slide
- Content
- Content

# Second horizontal slide
- Content
- Content

## First vertical slide
- Content
- Content
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just add the following css.

**style.css**

```css
section.level1 {
    top: 0px !important;
}
```

**presentation.qmd**

```
---
title: "My presentation"
format: revealjs
css: styles.css
---

# First horizontal slide
- Content
- Content

# Second horizontal slide
- Content
- Content

## First vertical slide
- Content
- Content
```

Comment: Great! I've been looking everywhere for a reference to get some guidance, can you point me to some resource? Thank you!

Comment: @Claudio, Resources to how to use CSS to change stuff in quarto? Simply click on the html element that you want to change and then click `inspect`. It will show you the underlying htmls. Just find out the css classes and make changes. But before that you need have clear understanding how html and css works.