# Quarto revealjs presentation vertical alignment of content

Tags: quarto, reveal.js

In using revealjs slides on Quarto the content is at the vertical middle of the slide (see image). As more content is added the heading moves up to make space. Is there a way to make sure that it is (1) aligned at the top or (2) starts from a point that is ten percent of the height below the top of the screen?

I tried using `center: false` but it does not work. The rest of my yaml header is as follows:

```yaml
---
format:
  revealjs: 
    width: 1600
    height: 900    
    margin: 0.1
    theme: simple
    slide-number: h.v
    navigation-mode: vertical
    center: false
    css: [custom.css]
---
```

[image]

Comment: Can you give a complete, minimal and reproducible example, not just the yaml section? My guess is, you are using Level-1 header (`#`) to create the slide, which is created as **title slide** and hence the content is vertically centered aligned. If you use Level-2 header (`##`) to create the slides, slide content should already be aligned as per your requirements.

Comment: However, if you want to top-align the title-slide (created with `#`) contents, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76754996/10858321)

Comment: That is correct. I am using # to create the header slides. My source on example on the Vertical Slides section in the [user guide](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/advanced.html#vertical-slides)